# Вращение камеры вокруг объекта gluLookAt

Tags: opengl

Мне нужно реализовать вращение камеры вокруг объекта c помощью функции gluLookAt. В общем, как стандартная камера в 3Ds Max.
В одной статье нашёл код, но он вращает камеру только по заданной оси через axis-angle вращения.

```
def Rotate_Position(self, angle, x, y, z):
    # Angle - угол вращения (разница между координатами мыши)
    # mPos - координаты камеры
    # mView - координаты точки, на которую смотрим
    self.mPos.x = self.mPos.x - self.mView.x
    self.mPos.y = self.mPos.y - self.mView.y
    self.mPos.z = self.mPos.z - self.mView.z

    vVector = self.mPos.copy()
    AVector = Vector3D()

    SinA = math.sin(math.pi * angle / 180.0)
    CosA = math.cos(math.pi * angle / 180.0)

    # Найдем новую позицию X для вращаемой точки 
    AVector.x = (CosA + (1 - CosA) * x * x) * vVector.x
    AVector.x += ((1 - CosA) * x * y - z * SinA) * vVector.y
    AVector.x += ((1 - CosA) * x * z + y * SinA) * vVector.z

    # Найдем позицию Y 
    AVector.y = ((1 - CosA) * x * y + z * SinA) * vVector.x
    AVector.y += (CosA + (1 - CosA) * y * y) * vVector.y
    AVector.y += ((1 - CosA) * y * z - x * SinA) * vVector.z

    # И позицию Z 
    AVector.z = ((1 - CosA) * x * z - y * SinA) * vVector.x
    AVector.z += ((1 - CosA) * y * z + x * SinA) * vVector.y
    AVector.z += (CosA + (1 - CosA) * z * z) * vVector.z

    self.mPos.x = self.mView.x + AVector.x
    self.mPos.y = self.mView.y + AVector.y
    self.mPos.z = self.mView.z + AVector.z
```

Есть ещё более простой метод. Он вроде как работает, правда, немного подёргивает камеру.

```
x = self.mView.x + math.sin(a)*math.cos(b)*r
z = self.mView.z + math.sin(a)*math.sin(b)*r
y = self.mView.y + math.cos(a)*r
```

Вроде бы и задача простая, но решения нормального найти нигде не могу.

Comment: "Он вроде как работает, правда, немного подёргивает камеру" - ищите в чем косяк. Ничего дергаться не должно.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы при достижении 90 градусов (смотрим на объект сверху) камера не поворачивалась, а крутилась дальше. Чтобы объект оказался перевёрнутым.

Comment: Обычно советуют перейти на кватернионы